# A 'Dense' Infinite Sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I want to evaluate the value of the following "power series": $$\sum_{q \in \Bbb{Q}_{\ge 0}}c_qz^q$$ with $c_q \in \Bbb{C}$ and $z \in \Bbb{C} \backslash \Bbb{R}^-$, where $z^q \overset{\operatorname{def}}{=}\operatorname{Exp}(q(\operatorname{ln}|z|+i\operatorname{arg}z)), \operatorname{arg}z\in(-\pi, \pi)$. To get a well-defined result, the sum is expected to be independent of the order of summation.

**Question 1:** is absolute convergence -- that is, replace $c_qz^q$ by $|c_q||z|^q$ and the sum (which is now independent of summation order because each term is positive) converges -- enough for the well-definition?

If so, what conditions does $\{c_q\}$ need to satisfy to make an absolute convergence at as many $z$ as possible? A possible example is $c_q=\frac{1}{f(q)!}$ and $|z| \le 1, z \notin \Bbb{R}^-$ where $f:\Bbb{Q}_{\ge 0} \to \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ is a bijective map.

If not, then how can we restrict $c_q$ or $z$ to make the sum well-defined? I do not want to give restriction to the summation order because the enumeration is too diverse to choose from thus may give uncertain result.

**Question 2:** what might the well-defined domain be? I assume it resembles an open disk with a radius off but I can not make any progress here due to the first question.

**Partial solution to question 1**:

For $|z| \le 1$, $|z|^q$ is bounded by $1$ so we only have to consider whether the convergence of $\sum_{q \in \Bbb{Q}_{\ge 0}}c_q$ is independent of summation order, and thus is equivalent to whether $\sum_{q \in \Bbb{Q}_{\ge 0}}|c_q|$ converges.

For $z$ with no restriction, I want to prove (but not done) that $$\exists f_0:\Bbb{Q}_{\ge 0} \to \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 0}, \operatorname*{\overline{lim}}_{f_0(q) \to +\infty}|c_q|^{\frac{1}{f_0(q)}}=\rho \\ \Rightarrow \forall f:\Bbb{Q}_{\ge 0} \to \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 0}, \operatorname*{\overline{lim}}_{f(q) \to +\infty}|c_q|^{\frac{1}{f(q)}}=\rho$$ which is possibly related to the potential convergence radius.

Comment: How is this sum defined?

Comment: @nombre The summation terms are countable so if the sum is independent of summation order then we can sum it in any order of the non-negative rational numbers.

Comment: My initial thought is that this isn't well-defined because it depends on which enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}_{\ge 0}$ you use.

Comment: @Integrand If for some $z_0$ the series converges uniformly then the sum is independent of the summation order when $z=z_0$.

Comment: Maybe my expression is not clear. I am asking when the sum is well-defined in my first question.

Comment: Why are you interested in this? What have you tried to answer your questions?

Comment: The problem I think is that if you take a sequence $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which has a lower bound $>0$ (in particular the set $\mathbb{Q} \setminus \{u_n \ : \ n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ must be infinite), then the sequence $(c_{u_n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ should tend to zero. Indeed there is $r \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}$ such that $(|c_{u_n}|r)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is summable.